# Error Sending mail in code igniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, email

I'm trying to send an email with [CodeIgniter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Codeigniter#CodeIgniter), but this is what I get:

> The following SMTP error was encountered: 110 Connection timed out
>   Unable to send email using PHP SMTP. Your server might not   configured to send mail using this method.

Here is my code in email.php:

```
<?php
    $CI =& get_instance();
    if ($CI->config->item('installed') == true) {
        $config['useragent']    = "CodeIgniter";
        $config['mailpath']     = "/usr/bin/sendmail"; // Or "/usr/sbin/sendmail"
        $config['wordwrap']     = TRUE;
        $config['mailtype']     = 'html';
        $config['charset']      = strtoupper(get_option('smtp_email_charset'));
        $config['newline']      = "\r\n";
        $config['crlf']         = "\r\n";
        $config['protocol']     = 'smtp';
        $config['smtp_host']    = get_option('smtp_host');
        $config['smtp_port']    = get_option('smtp_port');
        $config['smtp_timeout'] = '30';
        $config['smtp_user']    = get_option('smtp_email');
        $config['smtp_pass']    = get_option('smtp_password');

        // Set to "tls" if you need to use TLS
        $config['smtp_crypto'] = '';
    }
```